# php pdo_informix on windows 7 64 bit and wamp 64 bit

Tags: php, windows, wamp, informix

I try to install pdo_informix in WAMP 64 bit on windows 7 64 bit, but I found problem because pdo_informix.dll is version 32 bit. I try to search for pdo_informix.dll, but I can't found it. How to solve this problem?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  Good question.  Do you have the ability to compile C code on your machine?  If so, the fall-back option is to obtain the source and compile it for your system.  Offhand, I don't know where PDO Informix for 64-bit Windows can be downloaded, but I'd expect to find it at the same site as the 32-bit version can be downloaded from — certainly, that's where I'd look first.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you may have to download the source for PDO Informix and compile it; that is always an available option for open source (get the code and compile it) but it presumes you have the facilities needed to compile code.

A Google search with the terms 'pdo informix 64-bit windows' picks up this question, amongst others, and also points to the [PDO Informix](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-informix.php) manual which includes links to 'how to compile PDO extensions' etc.

Google also lists a [IIS forum](http://forums.iis.net/t/1187738.aspx/2/10) posting on the subject which says (lightly edited):

> As an alternative, there is a simpler option; however, it may not be ideal depending on your requirements. There is a tool called OpenAdmin Tool for Informix. This is a PHP-based tool for administrative tasks on an Informix database. The tool is a ready-built Apache webserver with PHP set up which uses the Informix pdo driver (it is actually embedded), however, the rest of it is the same, you could copy any extra extensions/modules from your existing setup over to the OpenAdmin PHP directory and enable them in the OpenAdmin php.ini file.Then put whatever ever resides in your existing htdocs folder into the OpenAdmin htdocs folder.

It lists links to the IBM site for OAT (OpenAdmin Tool), but the links embed the date 2006-01-26, so they're probably not current and likely not directly available.  The latest information is available from the [OpenAdmin Tool](http://openadmintool.org/) website.

OAT does not seem to be distributed for 64-bit Windows specifically.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem right now.

The OpenAdmin Tool website says that the Informix Client SDK which is available on the IBM website includes a ready-to-use OpenAdmin Tool including Apache Webserver, PHP and the pdo_informix extension.
However, the current SDK 4.10 is NOT shipped with the OpenAdmin Tool.

So you have to set up your own environment with Apache and PHP and the community edition of OpenAdmin Tool. I tried Apache 2.4 for x_86 and x_64 Systems (Windows) and all available Versions of PHP (5.4, 5.5, 5.6).

You can download the pdo_informix extension for PHP 5.4 here:
https://pecl.php.net/package/PDO_INFORMIX/1.3.1/windows

And there was a guy who compiled it for PHP 5.5:
https://github.com/maryo/php-5.5-windows-extensions/tree/master/php_pdo_informix-1.3.1-5.5-vc11-x86

There is also a hint that it is very important to set the INFORMIXDIR environment variable correctly. I tried several possibilities such as C:\Program Files\IBM Informix Software Bundle\ or with a trailing \bin but it did not help.

Unfortunately, nothing worked for me. The pdo_informix extension did not load. Hopefully I can help someone with my explanations to get the OAT up and running.